# Archiving Pages with Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I just started playing with Scrapy and my current goal is to build a webpage archiving tool.

So far I have this bit of code which saves a page to an .html file in the project folder.

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "testbot"
    allowed_domain = ["URL"]
    start_urls = ["URL"]

def parse(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

The above code works great but now how do I download all the pages assets. Images, CSS, JS

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For downloading assets, scrapy has the [Files and Images pipelines](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html?highlight=images). Or you can write you own custom pipeline for downloading the files (images, js, css). Next you need just extract the url addresses of the files from response and yield its to pipeline. For example like this:

```
def parse(self, response):

 links = response.selector.xpath("/html/head/link[@rel='stylesheet']")
 for style_link in links:
   yield {
       'type' : 'stylesheet',
       'url' : style_link.xpath('@href')
   }

 images = response.selector.xpath("//img")
 for img in images:
   yield {
       'type' : 'image',
       'url' : img.xpath('@src')
   }

 java_scripts = response.selector.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']")
 for js in java_scripts:
   yield {
       'type' : 'js',
       'url' : js.xpath('@src')
   }
```

it's a basic example how you cant do it. The format of the item can be different depending on the which pipeline you use.